# Stone theorem: how to identify |f|?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be an algebra of real continuous functions on compact set $K$. How to prove:

if $f \in \overline{\mathscr{A}}$, then $|f| \in \overline{\mathscr{A}}$.

By Rudin,  he assume $g = \sum_{i = 1}^n c_i f^i$. Since $\overline{\mathscr{A}}$ is an algebra, $f \in \overline{\mathscr{A}}$, then $g \in \overline{\mathscr{A}}$.

But my question is, the general form of the polynomials is:

$g = \sum_{i = 0}^n c_i f^i$, how to identify the constant function $1 \in \overline{\mathscr{A}}$?  In this case, does there exists $g \in \overline{\mathscr{A}}$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A hint:

You need a limiting argument to prove this. Here is a beginning:

The function $\phi(z):={\rm pv}\> (z+\epsilon^2)^{1/2}$ is analytic in the circle with center ${1\over2}$ and radius ${1\over2}+\epsilon^2$. Therefore it possesses a Taylor development of the form
$$\phi(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \beta_k \bigl(z-{1\over2}\bigr)^k$$
which converges *uniformly* on the interval $[0,1]$. So there is a polynomial $p$ with $|p(z)-\phi(z)|<\epsilon$ for all $z\in[0,1]$. As $|p(0)|<|\phi(0)|+\epsilon=2\epsilon$ we can replace $p$ with the polynomial $q(z):=p(z)-p(0)$, which has no constant term, and still have
$$|q(z)-\phi(z)|<3\epsilon\qquad\forall z\in[0,1]\ .$$
It follows that
$$q(t^2)-(t^2+\epsilon^2)^{1/2}|<3\epsilon\qquad\forall t\in[{-1},1]\ ,$$
and a simple argument lets one deduce that we can write
$$\bigl|q(t^2)-|t|\bigr|<4\epsilon\qquad\forall t\in[{-1},1]\ .$$
To apply this to the proof of the claim about $f$ and $|f|$ assume that $|f(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x\in K$.

Comment: Can I  conclude $1 \in \overline{\mathscr{A}}$ only from the condition $f \in \overline{\mathscr{A}}$ because $\mathscr{A}$ is any algebra of real continuous funtions. We does not know which function is contained in $\mathscr{A}$.

Comment: When ${\cal A}$ is a subalgebra of $C_0({\mathbb R})$ (continuous functions vanishing at infinity) then $1\notin\bar{\cal A}$. That's why we had to replace $p$ with $q$, which has no constant term.